# Can I update an eclipse plugin by dropping the newer JAR into the dropins directory?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have added a bug fix to one of my eclipse plugins. Now  I would like to update it.

I have built the org.eclipse.team.cvs.core plugin and have a newer version.

I dropped it into the dropins directory. Does that fix it?

Comment: Why don't you replace the old cvs plugins with the new plugins in <eclipseInstallationFolder>/plugins folder. Any reason to copy these to dropin folder? Usually dropin folder is used to install user plugins.

Comment: convert that to an answer plz. doesn't sound like anyone else has much to add?